# Error on using .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url, web

I'm trying to use my .htaccess file but I still can't figure it out what am I doing wrong.

I only want my domain to be yescpol.com.br, and it always comes like this [image: But I always have this problem]

My .htaccess is inside the folder "porcelanato" and it has this code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /porcelanato/
```

I only want my index.php to turn into yescpol.com.br

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have access to your apache config, this seems more like an issue with the `DocumentRoot` setting [See Docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#documentroot)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest thing to do would be to change the DocumentRoot in the domain configuration or move your files out of that folder and into the root.

If you want to stick with the rewrite method, you will need to add a rule like this.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ /porcelanato [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to the top of your .htaccess file:
`DirectoryIndex index.php`

Though if this property is set properly on your apache service in httpd.conf (or whatever is serving your pages) this won't have to be added to your .htaccess file.

Comment: Can you show me how your httpd.conf is setup?   I;articularly interested to see how this section is setup in your config for apache (if you are using apache that is).

Also please show me what your configuration looks like that directs the website in question to the document root.  

#
# DirectoryIndex: sets the file that Apache will serve if a directory
# is requested.
#
<IfModule dir_module>
        DirectoryIndex index.php index.php3 index.html index.htm
</IfModule>